# Set scrolling to only 4 elements in a slider using Owl Carousel?

Tags: javascript, carousel, owl-carousel

I want to scroll only 4 elements when I click on next or previous button of my Owl Carousel slider.

JS for slider is as follows:

```
$(".similarproducts").owlCarousel({
        items :5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
        itemsDesktop : [1000,3], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
        itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
        itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
        itemsMobile : [480,1] ,
        navigation:true,
        pagination:false,
        scrollPerPage : true,

      });
```

I used `scrollPerPage: true` but when I click on the next button it slides 5 elements, but I want to slide only 4 elements. Also, when the slider reaches it's end point I want it to bounce and don't move any further.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your items numberfrom 5 to 4
items:4 
I hope it will be donw

Comment: if i change it then my slider will show only 4 items but i need 5 items to show but when i click on next button it should scroll only 4 items

Comment: if you use owl carousel 2 then it will give you option how many slide you want to move set 
items:5,
slideBy: 4,
you can see 5 items but it will move 4

Answer (score 0):

add slideBy: "4" option or put any number you need also you can customize slidyBy on responsive option also

Comment: This answer can be added as a comment as it does not use examples.